# How to Response Destroy All Cookies from Server Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, response

i have cookies on the client-side `token=foobar;`, and i can delete cookies if i click the logout button with response server-side `response.clearCookie('token')`. the `'token'` is name of cookies. the question, i want to delete all cookies, how to clear all cookies? user can change the name of cookies or many more cookies on the client-side. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to try `response.clearCookie("*");`

UPDATE:

According to https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie, a name must be specified in order to clear a cookie, so clearing multiple cookies with express may not be an option.

I would look to a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/delete-all-cookies to solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried it, ```clearCookie()``` and ```clearCookie('*'). not working..